# Can't install Java in VirtualBox Win 7 VM from Modern.ie site

Tags: java, internet-explorer, windows-7, virtualbox

I downloaded a VM from the Microsoft "modern.ie" site to test IE10/Windows 7 on my Windows 7 computer (which has a different version of IE for testing sites).

It works fine, but our site requires the Java plugin.  So, I go to the site in the VM's copy of IE and download from the Java site, but the install always fails with this dialog:

[image]

No idea how to proceed, and nothing at that url about this situation either.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you still need help, but for those finding this thread all you have to do is manually download java instead of the installer via here:

https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp